# Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Naturalization (and Citizenship)?

Tags: discussion, challenge

It has been a slow week for questions on G&FH SE so I am going to declare the [top answer](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1897/19) (by score) to my [call for weekly challenge ideas](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off) a few hours early.

It was (by a tie break):

> In the USA, September 15th through October 15th is celebrated as
>   [German-American Heritage Month](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off), to commemorate the arrival of
>   German immigrants to the US on October 6th, 1683.
>
> One of the special challenges if you have immigrant ancestors in your
>   research is bridging the gap between the records in their new country,
>   and the records in their old one.
>
> The tag [immigration](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration) is well-represented with 46 questions, but
>   we have only 7 with the tag [naturalization](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naturalization).  However,
>   naturalization records often have the most precise information about
>   the place of origin of our immigrant ancestors.

Please use the [naturalization](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naturalization) tag for new questions and consider asking questions about naturalization (and citizenship) records kept in ANY new countries of immigrants from ANY old countries.

Next week, on 24 Oct, I will tally up the results to see how we did.

Answer (score 1):

During the week the challenge ran, the following [questions about Naturalization](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naturalization) were asked:

- [Becoming Australian citizens after British ancestors came to Australia?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6562/becoming-australian-citizens-after-british-ancestors-came-to-australia)
- [Children born overseas to British Subjects -- what is their citizenship status?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/children-born-overseas-to-british-subjects-what-is-their-citizenship-status)
- [Finding Naturalization Record for Hugh Sellars from Scotland who lived in Albany (New York State) 1855-1872?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/finding-naturalization-record-for-hugh-sellars-from-scotland-who-lived-in-albany)

These 3 questions attracted 7 answers from 4 answerers; well done!

To me, our top participant was:

[image: profile for Jan Murphy at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]

who not only provided a detailed question and/or answer in 2 of the 3 Q&As, and also the Challenge Topic!

Comment: Actually, no, I didn't write an answer for the first of these three questions. I only participated in two of those three.

Comment: Oops - you're right!  Not quite as omnipresent as I thought:-)