# Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Family Legends?

Tags: discussion, challenge

The Weekly Topic Challenge enters its second week and this week's challenge is:

> I just searched for mentions of **Family Legends** and found only one
>   such question for which I duly coined a new tag of
>   [family-legend](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-legend).
>
> That question came from @Fortiter and was
>   [Where do I look for a woman who vanished for 17 years?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/where-do-i-look-for-a-woman-who-vanished-for-17-years)
>
> By family legend I mean a story/legend that has been passed down to
>   you (most likely) by word of mouth, or perhaps has been written up
>   somewhere, but currently lacks any or sufficient corroborating
>   evidence for you to be confident that it is true.
>
> I think there must be many amazing Family Legends that could either
>   stand up or fall to closer scrutiny.

Please use the [family-legend](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-legend) tag for new questions and consider asking questions about legends or stories that have been told in your family for years, that may or may not stand up to closer scrutiny.  If any family legend/story that comes to your mind involves someone born less than 100 years ago please be extremely respectful of any living people who may not wish to see its details on a website.

Next week, on 31 Oct, I will tally up the results to see how we did.

We are running out of challenge topics so I encourage everyone to try to contribute a new one at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Answer (score 1):

During the week the challenge ran, the following questions about Family Legends were asked:

- [Was Robert John Steven Sellers first to cycle Adelaide to Melbourne?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/was-robert-john-steven-sellers-first-to-cycle-adelaide-to-melbourne)
- [Did uncle of Grace Martin Wills (or perhaps of Matthew Nettell) own the Gosforth?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/did-uncle-of-grace-martin-wills-or-perhaps-of-matthew-nettell-own-the-gosforth)

These 2 questions attracted 2 answers (both accepted) from the 2 answerers below; well done!

[image: profile for bgwiehle at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]

[image: profile for AdrianB38 at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]