# Who's that in your old family photo?

Tags: discussion, challenge

The Weekly Topic Challenge enters its fourth week and this week's challenge is:

> to identify details in an old photograph that you need help with.
>
> The photographs will preferably be of an individual (or small group)
>   and include any details that your research already suggests about who
>   it may be, and where and when it was taken.
>
> Additional information like a scan of the reverse side should be
>   included wherever possible, as well as how you came to be in
>   possession of the photo, etc.
>
> Looking back, examples of the types of question that I am thinking of
>   are:
>
> - [Dating this photograph of a younger Emma (Vig) Froiland](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/dating-this-photograph-of-a-younger-emma-vig-froiland)
> - [Dating/identifying a Duryea (mid-late 19th century) photograph from South Australia?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/dating-identifying-a-duryea-mid-late-19th-century-photograph-from-south-austral)
> - [Help determine date of photo from Tuscaloosa](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/help-determine-date-of-photo-from-tuscaloosa)

We will use a tag of [unidentified-photograph](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unidentified-photograph) for these questions so that we know they have been submitted as part of the challenge.

Note: This tag is designed to just be used to tally up the questions that come as part of the challenge and then those questions will be re-tagged to something more appropriate.

Next week, on 14 Nov, I will tally up the results to see how we did.

We are running out of challenge topics so I encourage everyone to try to contribute a new one at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Answer (score 1):

During the week the challenge ran, the following questions about Unidentified Photographs were asked:

- [Identifying photograph which may be Margaret Morgan (1808-1902) taken at Bridgend, Glamorgan, Wales?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/identifying-photograph-which-may-be-margaret-morgan-1808-1902-taken-at-bridgen)
- [Dating and identifying Penzance photos – are they of George and Fanny Wills?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/could-photos-be-george-wills-1806-1873-and-frances-fanny-angove-1815-1899)
- [Could photo be Edward Nettell (1812-1879) and Maria Hocking (1811-1902) of Illogan, Cornwall?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6634/could-photo-be-edward-nettell-1812-1879-and-maria-hocking-1811-1902-of-illog)

These 3 questions attracted only 1 answer (at least it was an accepted one) and while I could award the asker of all three questions this award, he is also the organizer, so instead it goes to someone who contributed the only, and excellent, answer:

[image: profile for Rusty Erpenbeck at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]