# WWI centenary and finding records about WWI service members

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

This was posted as a [proposal for a conference room chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/the-genealogy-conference-topics-for-focused-chats?lq=1).

Two of the big genealogy websites are having free access weekends this week in honor of the centenary of WWI.

**Find My Past** is/are offering everyone access to a World Subscription.

This is a link to the news item about the free weekend on their blog:
http://blog.findmypast.com/2014/enjoy-a-free-findmypast-world-subscription-this-weekend/

Everything is open from now until Monday (07:00am EST on  November 10th). 
Here's the link to the page which has the search form -- at the bottom they give the free access terms:
http://www.findmypast.com/freeweekend?_ga=1.107224839.487125391.1415134070

> Terms and Conditions
>
> ```
> Free access lasts from 7am (EST) on Friday 7th November 2014 until 06:59am (EST) on Monday 10 November 2014. To access the records you
> ```
>
> will need to be signed in at Findmypast: you can register for free
>   using your name, email address and country of residence. ... Free
>   access is subject to our fair usage policy: each account may view up
>   to a maximum of 1,000 records per day.

They have a live event on Saturday which can be viewed on the Internet, where several of their experts show how to look for records.  This is the link where the stream will be broadcast, starting at 10:00 Eastern on Saturday (in about 20 hours):
http://new.livestream.com/innerear/findmypast

**Ancestry.com** is also offering free access to some of their WWI military records this weekend. Here's their blog post showing what records they have:
http://blogs.ancestry.com/ancestry/2014/11/07/world-war-i-the-war-to-end-all-wars/#sthash.S6rmH2Jr

Email from Ancestry.co.uk gives the free access details:

> Access to the records in the featured collections will be free until
>   11 November 23:59 BST . After the free access period ends, you will
>   only be able to view the records in the featured collections using an
>   Ancestry.co.uk paid membership. To see a full list of the records in
>   the featured collections please click [here](http://www.ancestry.co.uk/cs/uk/world-war-1?o_xid=63142&o_lid=63142&o_sch=Email).

Ancestry.com also have a free guide on WWI records which is [available for download](http://www.ancestry.com/s62987/t31676/rd.ashx).
I invite anyone who wants to talk about search strategies on either service -- and how to use the information found on one service to seed a search on the other one -- to leave posts in the Conference Room this weekend during the free access period.  FindMyPast's free access window is already open.

Come share search techniques this weekend, then write up your findings in questions (and self-answers) afterwards.

P.S. FamilyRelatives.com posted a WWI Infographic on Google+. See it here:
http://www.familyrelatives.com/infographic_wwi.php