# Making the most of clues from Probate Records and Wills?

Tags: discussion, challenge

The Weekly Topic Challenge enters its sixth week and this week's challenge is:

> We currently have 9 questions with the tag [probate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probate).
>
> Wills are an especially rich source of names, which is a great way to
>   jumpstart cluster or FAN (friends, associates, neighbors) research. 
>   Even something as simple as an entry in the National Probate Index can
>   provide important clues.
>
> Looking back, examples of such questions are:

- [What does it mean if a probate index lists a person's record as "Insanity of", instead of "Estate of"?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/71/what-does-it-mean-if-a-probate-index-lists-a-persons-record-as-insanity-of-i)
- [What did it mean to come of age in 1684 at Saco (now Maine, USA)?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/206/what-did-it-mean-to-come-of-age-in-1684-at-saco-now-maine-usa)
- [Working with browsable images of probate records?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4158/working-with-unindexed-probate-records)
- [How to find Indentured Servants in Buffalo, NY or Canada?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/how-to-find-indentured-servants-buffalo-ny-or-canada)

We will use a tag of [probate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probate) for these questions coupled with their asking date so that we know they have been submitted as part of the challenge.

Next week, on 28 Nov, I will tally up the results to see how we did.

We have a few spare challenge topics so I encourage everyone to vote for which we do next at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Answer (score 1):

During the week the challenge ran, the following questions about Probate were asked:

- [Where to find Will of Giles Chichester from 1820s, probably in Somerset or Guyana?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/where-to-find-will-of-giles-chichester-from-1820s-probably-in-somerset-or-guyan)
- [Proving Jane Middleton of Somerset only Next of Kin in 1872 to Thomas Chichester who died 1838 in Guyana?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/proving-jane-middleton-of-somerset-only-next-of-kin-in-1872-to-thomas-chichester)

These 2 questions attracted 3 answers (none yet accepted but all very helpful) and this week I want to recognize an answerer who has provided some legal insights (at least to me):

[image: profile for user3310902 at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]