# Who needs help deciphering some old handwriting in family history documents?

Tags: discussion, challenge

The Weekly Topic Challenge enters its seventh week and this week's challenge is:

> What about tutorials on old scripts / old handwriting?

Use this challenge to pull out those hard to read Wills, Letters and other documents, and post questions about the words or groups of words that you are struggling to read and understand the meaning of.

A picture cropped from your document(s) will definitely be needed for this challenge!

Note: Please do not ask for transcriptions of whole documents.

Also, feel free to post questions about [palaeography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaeography) in general like [Is there a transcription standard that separates unclear words from added words?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/is-there-a-transcription-standard-that-separates-unclear-words-from-added-words)

Looking back, examples of questions we are looking for this week are:

- [What is the Russian town in this census listing?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/what-is-the-town-in-this-census-listing)
- [Determining what old document with Illegible handwriting says?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/how-can-i-determine-what-an-old-document-with-illegible-handwriting-says)
- [Can anyone decipher the comment above Louis' name on this 1940 census record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2470/can-anyone-decipher-the-comment-above-louis-name-on-this-1940-census-record)
- [Help needed reading a place of birth in an 1871 census record from Glamorgan, Wales](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/help-needed-reading-a-place-of-birth-in-an-1871-census-record-from-glamorgan-wa)
- [Old German script. What is the wife's name in this 1837 baptismal ledger from Stark County, Ohio?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/old-german-script-what-is-the-wifes-name-in-this-1837-baptismal-ledger-from-st)
- [Meaning of “dofhoadayne” in 1648 Will of William Noake from Longburton, Dorset, England?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/meaning-of-dofhoadayne-in-1648-will-of-william-noake-from-longburton-dorset)

We will use a tag of [palaeography](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palaeography) for these questions coupled with their asking date so that we know they have been submitted as part of the challenge.

Next week, on 5 Dec, I will tally up the results to see how we did.

Answer (score 1):

During the week the challenge ran, only one question was asked about deciphering old handwriting:

- [Was William Chichester recorded as Judge in 1841 Census at Dymock, Gloucestershire, England?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6679/was-william-chichester-recorded-as-judge-in-1841-census-at-dymock-gloucestershi)

This question attracted just one answer which was both highly upvoted and accepted which makes the decision on who to recognize this week easy:

[image: profile for AdrianB38 at Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange, Q&A for expert genealogists and people interested in genealogy or family history]