# Ask your ANZAC ancestry questions on 100th anniversary of Gallipoli landing!

Tags: discussion, challenge

For our first Topic Challenge of 2015, I am setting one from World War I:

> Do you have any ancestors connected to the Australian and New Zealand
>   Army Corps [(ANZAC) landing at Gallipoli](http://www.anzacsite.gov.au/) in Turkey which occurred on 25
>   April 1915 i.e. the 100th anniversary is now less than 3 weeks away? 
>   Feel free to ask questions about their lives before, during and
>   hopefully after the end of World War I.  There is now great and
>   lasting friendship and respect between those descended from the ANZACs
>   and the Turkish defenders so it would be fantastic to see questions
>   from both sides engaged in that struggle.  And, of course, any World War I 
>   questions are always welcome related to any of its events.

A quick search here reveals that to date we have had no questions, and only [one answer that mentions Gallipoli](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/8041/19).

To ask a question [click here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) but if you are new to the Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange then be sure to take our [2-minute Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) first.

After ANZAC Day (25 April) I will tally up the results to see how we did.

After this special challenge, I plan to pose more challenges.  We have a few spare challenge topics so I encourage everyone to suggest new ones and vote for which to do next at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the weeks the challenge ran, the following questions mentioning Gallipoli were asked:

- [Interpreting Service Record of QAIMNS nurse in Egypt at time of Gallipoli campaign?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8074/interpreting-service-record-of-qaimns-nurse-in-egypt-at-time-of-gallipoli-campai)
- [Finding B.213 forms for Australian Nurse serving mainly in Egypt during World War I?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/finding-b-213-forms-for-australian-nurse-serving-mainly-in-egypt-during-world-wa)

These 2 questions attracted 2 answers (one accepted), both on the same question.