# Was your ancestor in a fraternal organization?

Tags: discussion, challenge

For our next Topic Challenge of 2015, I am setting one from @JanMurphy:

> We have some questions about the Masons already. There are MANY other
>   fraternal organizations. I'm sure if we scoured our records, we could
>   find people who belonged to the Masons, other fraternal orders, or
>   other social organizations.
>
> The orders themselves may have indexes of members with just a few
>   dates involving their membership in the organization, but they can
>   provide vital clues to residence in a particular area, and membership
>   information may lead to hits in newspapers or city directories,
>   yielding names of associates for cluster / FAN group research.

A quick search here reveals that to date we have had these [questions that mention "mason"](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=mason+is%3Aquestion) so to widen the net let's have questions about:

- Freemasons;
- other fraternal organizations and lodges; and
- the occupation of Mason

To ask a question [click here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) but if you are new to the Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange then be sure to take our [2-minute Tour](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) first.

After a couple of weeks I will tally up the results to see how we did.

If you have an idea for a new challenge or want to see a re-run of an earlier one then I encourage you to suggest new ones and vote for which to do next at [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)

Comment: My grandfather was a Mason. I don't have any questions about it though.

Comment: @JustinY do you know his mother lodge and other membership information?

Comment: The info isn't handy but I think it's available somewhere. Why?

Comment: @JustinY Knowing who else was a member of the same lodge is useful for researching the FAN club (friends, associates, neighbors).  Using a US Mason's membership card that listed the mother lodge, I was able to get residence information in Scotland for someone in my tree.  When I am studying immigrants, every scrap of information I can get helps to determine the identify of the person in a particular record -- whether the record belongs to 'my person' or someone else with the same name.

Comment: @JanMurphy That makes sense, though I know plenty about my grandfather and his family. It's his great-grandparents that are my closest mystery.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of this topic challenge one new question related to it appeared:

- [Where to donate records related to South Australian United Ancient Order of Druids?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8141/where-to-donate-records-related-to-south-australian-united-ancient-order-of-drui/8148#8148)

It attracted two high quality answers, so thank you to those who participated.