# Weekly Topic Challenge: Finding and using Probate records

Tags: discussion, challenge

It has been a while since we had a Topic Challenge.  Let's ask questions -- or share our prior work with self-answered questions -- about probate records.  How can you find them?  What pointers can they give to other records?  What finding aids and research guides exist?

Please use the [probate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probate) tag for new questions.

Next week we will tally up the results to see how we did.

We are running out of challenge topics so I encourage everyone to try to contribute a new one at [Weekly Topic Challenge needs more Challenge Topics](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/weekly-topic-challenge-not-to-be-confused-with-weekly-chat-kicks-off)!

Comment: Ancestry is featuring a new collection of probate records which is free to access through Monday 7 September.  Their free guide to searching for Probate records is at http://c.mfcreative.com/mars/landing/probates/ProbatesResearchGuide_final.pdf

Answer (score 1):

And the results are:

Top Questioner: [vervet](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/1107/vervet)

- [Accuracy of place of death recorded in the National Probate Calendar?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9691/1006) asked Sep 15
- [Identifying difficult words in 1651 will?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9639/1006) asked Aug 28
- [How to cite the National Probate Calendar?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9624/1006) asked Aug 23
- [Searching databases for ancestors with aliases?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9617/1006) asked Aug 22

Top answerer: [AdrianB38](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/310/adrianb38)

- A: [Accuracy of place of death recorded in the National Probate Calendar?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9693/1006)
- A: [How to cite the National Probate Calendar?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9626/1006)

Thanks also to [PolyGeo](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/19/polygeo?tab=profile) for his question:

- [Finding wills/probate for printers of Brecon, Wales who died in 1794, 1820 and 1839?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9622/1006) asked Aug 23

and to AntonyM, TomH for answers, plus everyone who left comments.

If you have a proto-answer left in comments, think about ways those could be turned into answers.

Thanks to all our community members who made contributions during the Probate Topic Challenge!