# Topic challenge: Need help with discovering Migration Patterns?

Tags: discussion, challenge

One of the ways we create brick walls for ourselves is by assuming that our people stayed in the same place for their entire lives.  If a family suddenly disappears from their community - where did they go?

Ask your questions about your wandering families -- or write up your own discoveries with a self answered-question -- and tag them [migration](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration).

For previous questions tagged with this topic, [search on the tag](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration).

If there's a particular Topic Challenge you'd like to see, post your ideas in [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1894/1006)

---

Since posting this challenge, the US National Archives has announced its 2015 Virtual Genealogy Fair, a two-day schedule of livestreamed lectures featuring the records held in the archives and how to use them for genealogical research.

The first presentation on Day 2, at 10 AM Eastern, 22 October 2015, is on migration:

> **Where’d They Go? Finding Ancestral Migration Routes** presented by Jean Nudd, National Archives at Boston
>
> Our ancestors were
>   mobile, and families moved, sometimes across an ocean but just as
>   often via land routes to the western frontier. Where they went, how
>   they got there, and why they moved adds flavor and depth to our
>   research and family knowledge. This lecture outlines some of the
>   Federal and local records that can be used for this research.

The handout for this presentation is an article that has already been published in NARA's Prologue Magazine, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2014/winter/migration.pdf).

Many of the record groups shown in the article are unique to the USA, but some of the techniques (using record groups in combination) may be applicable to other localities.

---

Ancestry.co.uk is offering free access to a collection of migration records during the weekend of 2 October -- access to the records in the featured collections will be free until 4 October, 2015 at 23:59 BST.