# Topic challenge: Making effective use of burial and cemetery records

Tags: discussion, challenge

For Halloween / The Day of the Dead, let's focus on cemetery records.  If you've found them to be helpful in your research, post a self-answered question and show everyone what you discovered.  If you've got a stumper about finding a burial, write up a question.

If there's a particular Topic Challenge you'd like to see, post your ideas in [Vote for the next Topic Challenge!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1894/1006)

Comment: Free access to cemetery databases at NEHGS this weekend: https://twitter.com/AncestorExperts/status/660219618284412929