# March Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Divorce

Tags: discussion, challenge

Today begins the first of a series of [Monthly Topic Challenges](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/). This month let's look more closely at our ancestors' **divorces**.

We've all got them in our family trees. But...

- Do you have your ancestor's divorce records?
- Do you have an ancestor for whom you've lost the paper trail, and can't rule out that they divorced?
- Do you know why your ancestor divorced?
- Do you know about the divorce process they went through?
- Do you know about the divorce laws when and where your ancestors lived?

If you can answer "no" to any of these – [**ask a question**](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about it! Use the [divorce-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divorce-records) for any questions about divorce.

At the end of the month we'll tally up the [divorce-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divorce-records) questions and answers and a very special one-of-a-kind life-changing mostly transparent prize will be awarded to the top questioner and answerer on this topic.

In the meantime please continue to [propose and vote](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/) on future topics ideas for the topic you would like to be selected for April.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was just about the biggest failure of a topic challenge, ever. There were 0 questions about this topic asked during the month of March.

As there generally seems to be very minimal interest in the idea of Topic Challenges at the moment, I'll suspend starting another one for now. If you would like to see them back please post and vote on ideas at: [Monthly Topic Challenges 2017 – Propose and vote on future topics](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/monthly-topic-challenges-2017-propose-and-vote-on-future-topics).

Comment: It was perhaps a very minority interest.... But persona;ly, I have no interest in topic challwnges -- I ask questions as they arise, not because this site suggest them.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl That is kind of the point of challenges – to prompt you to ask questions that you otherwise might not have thought of. Anyway, as I said, we'll hold off on starting any more until there is some real interest

Comment: I'm a contrary so-and-so, and can come up with questions without any prompts.  But others may find them useful -- perhaps if they were less specialised to start with?  I've only got three divorces in my family history and they're all so recent they're covered by privacy laws. I'll put my thinking cap on and see if I can come up with something tha tmight work.

Comment: I'm sorry @HarryVervet -- I did have one bit of research I could have written up, but the calendar got away from me. How did it get to be April so soon?